Connect the dots x Crosswords
About the puzzle:
This puzzle is a crossover of "connect the dots" puzzles and crossword puzzles. It requires the solver to place dots on the graph using crossword-like clues. Then, dots must be connected in order (1st to 2nd, 2nd to 3rd and so on). However, you can place dots in any order you like.
Every dot/point on the graph has 2 clues: one for X coordinate and one for Y coordinate. Each clue refers to something that has a numerical part in its name or other parameters.
Clues may consist of several parts which are combined via mathematical operators such as: x, +, /, ^, -,    $\sqrt{}$ (sqrt)
Clues may have hidden parts that are answers, for example - The *** Towers - The Two Towers - A J. R. R. Tolkien's book. The hidden part can be a word or a number.
All numbers are in base 10.
The goal of the solver is to guess what the connected dots represent.

Example of a clue and corresponding point:
Clue - [The first time Ocean did a heist; How many houses are there in Hogwarts?]
Point - [11; 4]
The X coordinate is "Ocean's Eleven", the Y coodrinate corresponds to the number of houses in Hogwarts (4).

The graph:

You may use your version of this graph, but it must be a square grid and have the same coordinate range (or bigger).

The dots/points.
This puzzle has 2 groups of dots. They are independent from one another.
Group 1:



Point
X
Y




1
Infinity's little cousin
Baby Queen *********


2
Olympic rings
The fifth centered triangular number


3
Ti
Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything


4
**** seasons x Week
ASCII "*"


5
Li ^ *****-body problem
The Last Supper x minimum points to define a plane


6
January, March, May, July, August, October or December
Bees' favourite polygon ^ sides of a coin


7
Palpatine's famous order / Earth poles
sqrt(Hoover Dam completion)


8
F-** Raptor x most mammals' eyes
Two fortnights


9
Around the World in ****** Days / He
February's most romantic day


10
The integer bits
Most ominous Friday


11
Ne + P
The element required for bone development


12
The oldest of the teens
Dartboard sectors



Group 2:



Point
X
Y




1
The Lucky ** casino
Most used dice in board games


2
The sum of the first 3 positive cubes
Windows version released in 2015


3
Pt / "Just the *** of us"
deca-





What kind of answer is expected? A name for the picture formed? I've solved all the clues except the first Y clue and have two sets of lines. Plainly the second group form a triangle. I've no idea what it is supposed to be a picture of.

@PDT - I'm referring to "*" character, which belongs to printable original ASCII characters as far as I understand.

@WeatherVane - correct, the answer is expected to be the name for the picture that is formed by the connected dots, that is the goal after all. Also, preferably, the answer should contain an image where the dots are connected and a table with solved clues.

The answer is

 Australia


 

I may have got some of them wrong especially Y1 because I've found a connection with the number

 23, a song by Baby Queen, but this doesn't line up with the asterisks

However "The goal of the solver is to guess what the connected dots represent." so I don't think it makes that much of a difference.
Here is the coordinates for the first group:



 8 (∞ cousin) 23 (the song by Baby Queen)




 5 (number of olympic rings) 31 (the 5th centered triangular number)




 22 (titanium) 42 :)




 28 (4x7) 42 (ascii code of the asterisk)




 27 (3^3) 39 (Jesus and the 12 apostles x 3)




 31 (days in the month) 36 (6^2)




 33 (66/2) 44 (sqrt(1936))




 44 (F-22 Raptors x 2) 28 (2x14 days)




 40 (80 days / Helium=2) 14 (valentines)




 32 (size of an int) 13 (spooky)




 25 (neon + phosphor) 20 (calcium)




 19 (after that it's the beginning of the end) 20



Group 2:



 38 (Fallout) 6 (D6)




 36 10




 39 (Platinum/2) 10




You guessed correctly! 1st point in group 1 is (8; 17). Baby Queen Seventeen is a song by Marko Polo :)
